# python create a new csv and populate header row from list

Tags: python, csv

I need to create a new csv file using python and populate header row from my list. I have:

```
with open ('Result.csv','w') as fp:
    a=csv.writer(fp,delimiter=',')
    a.writerows(list1)
```

and

```
list1 =['DATE','DATASET','BUILD'.....]
```

problem is my result is each letter gets written into one cell, so instead of having the first cell ="DATE", I have the first 4 cells as: "D","A","T","E". How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `writerows` expects a list of iterables. You are passing a list of iterables (a list of strings). What you intend is that strings are dumped, not iterated. Try this:

```
a.writerows([list1])
```

@alecxe told you how to put a single row with `a.writerow`, which is an alternative. If you want, however, to dump a big bunch of rows together with the header, you could try:

```
a.writerows([list1] + listOfDataRows)
```

provided you already collected the rows in `listOfDataRows` (a list of iterables).

Answer (score 2):

Normally `writerows()` is used to write *multiple rows* and expects an iterable with rows inside.

You meant to use [`writerow()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow) instead to write a single row:

```
a.writerow(list1)
```